# Posting to a wall on Facebook for a fan page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, http-post, facebook-page, facebook-php-sdk

Using the current PHPSDK and API (ie not FBJS or the REST approach) I am trying to work out how to paste to a fanpage wall and struggling to find any hints...

I have successfully (through various attempts)
posted to my wall
posted to a friend's wall
posted to the page's wall (when I like the page before posting)
posted to the page's wall (as the page)

So I am looking to work out what I need to do to access_code/permissions or code to have something like :

```
$result = $facebook->api(
    '/<PAGEID>/feed/',
    'post',
    array('access_token' => <ACCESSCODE>, 'message' => 'Test message')
    );
```

or

```
FB.api('/<PAGEID>/feed', 'post', {access_token:<ACCESSCODE>, message:'Test message'},     
function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert(response.error.message);
    } else {

    } 
});
```

working where a post will appear on the feed of page's wall... However I am currently unable to find a way to post to a page wall for a page that I have not explicitly said I like by using the Graph API in PHP...

I am sure it is possible judging by some of the page walls I have seen.

Searching on google and forums tends to lead to old API implementations (which no longer function) or using methods no longer supported. It seemed that the Templatized function could have been what I was looking for (but again that has been deprecated).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have one of the page administrators give your app "publish_stream" permission. Something like this:

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$perms = 'publish_stream';
echo '<fb:login-button perms="' . $perms . '"></fb:login-button>';
```

Once the click the button and approve you, your callback url will get called with their session information.

Once you have that you can post to the wall of any page they administer. Using code like what you show in your question.